# Multiple subdomain in single host

Tags: docker, server, routes

I'm using 1 host for hosting several service, all on docker. Each of service have a domain like service.domain.com.
I'm using haproxy as a router. The problem is it has a dead time when you change the configuration (haproxy.cfg). How can I solve this? Another solution than haproxy or...?
PS: I'm using windows server 2016 and docker for windows.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need orchestration tool like Kubernetes and run HaProxy inside kubernetes. To make changes, create new docker images and deploy using RollingUpdate strategy, that way you will not loose connections.